# Error on if with file_get_contents()

Tags: php

I was trying to do an 'search for updates page' with php with this code:

```
<?php
    $update = file_get_contents('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/esteves25566/gestordebiblioteca/master/updater');
    if ($update == "build001"){
    }else{
        echo "<p style= \"color:red\">Existe um novo update! A nova build é a $update</p>";
    }
?>
```

But when the site output is build001, the if sentence go to read it as false, printing "Existe um novo update! A nova build é a build001"
I already try everyting!
Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: did you try a var_dump($update) to see what you have to match to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an unprintable character at the end of build001, its a newline character by the looks of it.

Try this test

```
<?php
    $update = file_get_contents('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/esteves25566/gestordebiblioteca/master/updater');
    if ($update == "build001\n"){
        echo 'gotit';
    }else{
         echo "<p style= \"color:red\">Existe um novo update! A nova build é a $update</p>";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand you here, but

```
$update = file_get_contents('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/esteves25566/gestordebiblioteca/master/updater');
if ( trim( $update ) <> 'build001') {
  echo '<p style="color:red">Existe um novo update! A nova build é a ' . $update . '</p>';
  exit();
}
```

Comment: You should write what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the both questions!!! It has been resolved.
Both questions work but i prefer this because i think is more easy!!

```
<?php
$update = file_get_contents('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/esteves25566/gestordebiblioteca/master/updater');
if ($update == "build001\n"){
    echo 'gotit';
}else{
     echo "<p style= \"color:red\">Existe um novo update! A nova build é a $update</p>";

}
?>
```

Thanks a lot!